# is "set a = 2 and b in (1,2,3)" valid mysql syntax

Tags: mysql

Is it valid mysql to use "and" in place of "where" when it's used in the set clause? I recently tracked down a key constraint error to this, but it's been in place for a while and never been a problem as far as I know.

```
update table1
    join table2 on
        table1.id = table2.id
set table1.foo = 2
    and table1.bar in (1,2,3)
```

I set the last "and" to "where" and the code worked. As far as I could tell the values it's updating wouldn't result in a key constraint.

EDIT:
Updated the query to more closely resemble the original, but the same principle applies.

Comment: It is invalid syntax. SQL can be very complicated and often counter-intuitive, so don't be shy about [checking the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) on how any given command is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` can not be used with `set` but can be used with `where`

> UPDATE table_name  SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...  WHERE
>   condition;

so your sql need to be changed:

```
update table1
    join table2 on
        table1.id = table2.id
set table1.foo = 2,table1.bar = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing that `and` to `where` makes two completely different queries. Your WHERE version would set foo to 2 on all rows **where** the bar value is equal to 2. The AND version, if it works, would at best set foo equal to the boolean result of `(2 AND (bar is equal to 2))`, for all rows.